# select dropdown selected not currently working properly in vue js using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Hi i have this select dropdown that will be selected on the edit page. Now my problem is i have already the code but it seems its not working. Here is the code below.

```
<div id="app-accomodation-type-private">
                    <select name="accomodationType" id="form_type" data-style="btn-selectpicker" title="" aria-describedby="propertyTypeHelp" class="selectpicker form-control">
                      <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                      <optgroup v-for="(group, name) in optionGroups" :label="name">
                          <option v-for="option in group" :value="option.value" :selected="option.value =={{ json_encode($postRoom['accomodation_type']) }}?true : false">
                            @{{ option.text }}
                          </option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Now my vue js script

```
<script>
    //accomodation type private room
    new Vue({
    el: '#app-accomodation-type-private',
        data: {
          //selected: 'A',
          optionGroups: {
            PrivateRoom: [
              { text: 'Single Bed', value: 'Single Bed' },
              { text: 'Double Bed', value: 'Double Bed' },
              { text: 'Queen Size Bed', value: 'Queen Size Bed' },
              { text: 'Barkada', value: 'Barkada' }
            ],
            Tent: [
              { text: 'Tent', value: 'Tent' },
              { text: 'Hammock', value: 'Hammock' }
            ]
          }
        }
    })



</script>
```

Now what seems to be the problem? Can someone help me figured this thing out? TIA

Comment: I suspect there will be some warning or error in your browser it's developer console. If so, could you provide it?

Comment: Please be more specific on what you mean with "seems its not working.". Post warnings, errors or the difference on what you get and what you expected

Comment: okay i will try to look on it

Comment: the select dropdown selected wont work

Comment: hello! i can't see why its not working